# How to make sure that the DOM elements I want to manipulate have loaded before trying to do anything with them in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I've been battling this problem since yesterday and I'm at my wits end. Currently, I have a method in vue file that does this:

```
methods: {
    showSlides(n) {
        let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

        slides[0].style.display = "block";
    }
},
mounted(){
    this.showSlides();
}
```

It finds all elements with the class of "mySlides", stores them in a variable and then attempts to change the style of the first element. This function is called when the component is mounted().

Now, the problem is that I get an error which states `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined"`. Turns out that at the time of execution of this function, these DOM elements are undefined. I realized this by adding a `@click='showSlide()'` event to a button. When I click the button, the function runs successfully, however, when it is mounted() it doesn't.

The code also works successfully in a plain HTML file where the script is at the bottom of the page. This is what leads me to believe that something fishy is going on.

Full Code:

```
<template>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="sight-container">
            <p class='sight-name'>{{ sight.name }}</p>
            <p>{{ sight.formatted_address }}</p>
            <p>{{ sight.formatted_phone_number }}</p>
            <p>{{ sight.international_phone_number }}</p>
            <p>{{ sight.website }}</p>


            <div class="photos-container">
                <div v-for='(image, index) in sightImages' class="mySlides">
                    <div class="numbertext">{{ index + 1 }} / {{ sightImages.length }}</div>
                    <img class='sight-photos'  :src="'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=1920&photoreference=' + image.photo_reference + '&key='">
                </div>

                <a class="prev" @click='plusSlides(-1)'>❮</a>
                <a class="next" @click='plusSlides(1)'>❯</a>

                <div class="caption-container">
                    <p id="caption"></p>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div v-for='(image, index) in sightImages' class="column">
                      <img class="demo cursor" :src="'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=1920&photoreference=' + image.photo_reference + '&key='" style="width:100%" @click="currentSlide(1)">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios'

    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                placeId: this.$route.params.placeid,
                sight: "",
                sightImages: [],
                slideIndex: 1
            }
        },
        methods: {
            showSlides(n) {
                let i;
                let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
                let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
                let captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

                if (n > slides.length) {
                    this.slideIndex = 1
                }
                if (n < 1) {
                    this.slideIndex = slides.length
                }
                for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                    slides[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
                    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
                }

                slides[this.slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
                dots[this.slideIndex-1].className += " active";
                captionText.innerHTML = dots[this.slideIndex-1].alt;
            },
            plusSlides(n) {
                this.showSlides(this.slideIndex += n);
            },
            currentSlide(n) {
                this.showSlides(this.slideIndex = n);
            }
        },
        mounted(){
            axios.get('/getSight/' + this.placeId)
            .then(response => {
                this.sight = response.data.result.result
                this.sightImages = response.data.result.result.photos
            }).catch((error) => console.log(error));

            this.showSlides(this.slideIndex);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Show your template, please.

Comment: Added full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're using it wrong.

Normally, `mounted` are called *after* rendering component's DOM, at this time component's `this.$el` is ready to be used.

However, in `mounted` you're calling *asynchronous* operation that updates `data` (and later DOM) upon completion, but you try to use its result *before* it happened.

It should be like this:

```js
mounted() {
  axios.get('/getSight/' + this.placeId)
       .then(response => {
         this.sight = response.data.result.result;
         this.sightImages = response.data.result.result.photos;
         this.$nextTick(() => {
           this.showSlides(this.slideIndex);
         });
       }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
}
```

---

Small hint: rather than use `el.className += ...` and `el.className.replace(...)` you can use `el.classList.add(...)` and `el.classList.remove(...)`.

Docs: [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: So even though the function call is executed after the GET ( the call is below the GET request code ), the elements  which are created using the response from the GET still don't exist?

Comment: @Bobimaru Function call executed _before_ `GET`, because `axios.get` call is _asynchronous_. It's like this: 1) GET request queued (async); 2) function call; 3) GET request executed; 4) GET response received; 5) component's data changed; 6) DOM updated

Comment: Oh wow, that is interesting. Everything works smoothly now. Thanks a lot.